# show to specify condition for back button path in android

Tags: android

In my app 10 screens are there ,i can go to screen 10 from remaining 9 screens , here if ii press device back button then app showing previous screen but i would lite to change the path if screen 10 is redering from screen2 how can i specify condition for that only.

Comment: here i am using finish() in onBackPressed() for moving to previous screen

Comment: Considering that you get abusive and use derogatory words and statements, I am not editing this question. Instead merely pointing out the mistakes. Use `I` instead of `i`. Punctuation should have a ` ` after not before. Correct the `ii` to `I`. Separate the question neatly into sentences, this wall of text is not useful. Also google a bit before you ask questions. You can search for `override back press action android`. The first 10 links are what you need. This question is not worthy of SO. Read the FAQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method is probably to provide a unique extra inside the `Intent` you use to launch that Activity each time, representing the screen you are coming from so you can modify the behavior as you see fit in `onBackPressed()`.

For example, from any Activity X that launches "screen 10":

```
Intent intent = new Intent(...);
intent.putExtra("from_screen", x); //where x is a unique number or some other identifier
startActivity(intent);
```

Then, in `onBackPressed()` of the destination Activity, you can inspect the extra from the `Intent` that launched that Activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent callingIntent = getIntent();
    int callingScreen = callingIntent.getIntExtra("from_screen", -1);

    //Do some logic based on the screen you came from
    switch(callingScreen) {
        case 1:
            //Magic action when we came from screen 1
            break;
        case 5:
            //Magic action when we came from screen 5
            break;
        default:
            //Normal for everyone else, which is to just finish()
            super.onBackPressed();
            break;
    }
}
```

Make sure to call `super` in cases where you don't want the behavior modified as well.

Comment: here the problem is logic ,how can i specify that condition

Comment: suppose i am moving to screen10 from screen1 but if i click on back in screen10 i want to go to some other screen

Comment: @user2218563 Then instead of calling `finish()` or `super` in that case you would construct a new `Intent` and call `startActivity()` from inside `onBackPressed()`.  Although I should note that starting a new screen from a back press is discouraged behavior as it is confusing to the user.

Comment: i know how to start an activity using intent problem is specifying condition ,how can i specify a condition in onBackPressed()

Comment: i.e called screen = screen10 and calling screeen = scrren1 then how can i form a condition here

Comment: I think I understand the part you think you're missing, so I added a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would suggest is using the andriod manifest. In the activity node that you want to skip back from,

```
<activity android:name="com.example.app.ACTIVITY_FROM" >
        <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.app.ACTIVITY_TO_GO_TO" />
</activity>
```

Where ACTIVITY_FROM is the activity name you are pressing the back button in and ACTIVITY_TO_GO_TO is the activity you want the button to bring you to. In the meta data node, the `android:name` part needs to be left as is, this is saying that the parent of the current activity should be considered the `android:value` activity.